# Insert values into table where one value represents a value in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table 'item' in a postgresql database containing: 
`(itemid, typeid, barcode, serialnumber)`

```
CREATE TABLE item
    (itemid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    typeid INTEGER,
    barcode TEXT UNIQUE,
    serial TEXT,
    eventid INTEGER,
    out_noteid INTEGER,
    in_noteid INTEGER,
    temp SMALLINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (typeid) REFERENCES type(typeid),
    FOREIGN KEY (eventid) REFERENCES event(eventid)
)
```

I have another table 'type' created by

```
CREATE TABLE type
  (typeid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  bookingid TEXT UNIQUE,
  description TEXT,
  category TEXT,
  replacementprice TEXT,
  forcelabel SMALLINT,
  image BYTEA
);
```

I have data from another application supplied as:  `(bookingid, barcode, serial)` , this is being imported into my application in python from a csv file and will be along the lines of  `('666666-', 'barcode8739127', 'serial491257h45')`

I can't work out the correct sql query in postgresq; to insert this data into the table 'item' as (typeid, barcode, serialnumber), referencing bookingid to typeid.

Sample data in `type` might be  `typeid='2', bookingid='666666-'`

So the data I want to insert into item is  `('2', 'barcode8739127', 'serial491257h45') as (typeid, barcode, serial)`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I'm *guessing* you'd look up `type` using the input `bookingid`, giving you `typeid`, which you would then use when creating your `item` row - but as I say that's a guess. Please **edit your question** and include examples of what's in your `type` table and what the input you're getting looks like. Thanks.

Comment: Have edited to make it clear - yes that is what I want to do, just can't work out how to write the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO item (typeid, barcode, serial)
VALUES((SELECT typeid FROM type WHERE bookingid = '666666-'),'barcode8739127','serial491257h45')
```